# Android get EditText line count after each inserted new line

Tags: android

by this below code i'm trying to show `EditText` line count after inserting new line, this code work fine only for first new line and after that, for each type character into `EditText` i get inserted new line log on `LogCat`

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (-1 != text.toString().indexOf("\n")) {
            Log.e("new line ", "enter new line" + "");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: you will get new line for each character.  `indexOf("\n")` always returns some value because if first new line occured. then in that text a new line is present there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
        String insertedString =  text.toString();
        if (text.length() > 0 && insertedString.substring(insertedString.length() - 1).equals("\n")) {
             Log.e("new line ", "enter new line " + (channelMessageBox.getLineCount() - 1));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is not working. He didnt read your question at all. With this code, you will count the first line, and then it will stop. Just count the \n characters and you are good to go, instead of looking for the index.

Comment: @Amy please change `/n` to `\n`, now how can i get line count?

Comment: @Amy i update your code to: `if (text.length() > 0 && insertedString.substring(insertedString.length() - 1).equals("\n")) {
       Log.e("new line ", "enter new line " + (channelMessageBox.getLineCount() - 1));
   }`

Answer (score 2):

You have to count newline:

```
int counter = 0;

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(before==0) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.toString().length(); i++) {
                if (text.toString().charAt(i) == '\n') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("total new line ", "counter: " + counter);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: its not good solution, because for each typing character you have to check that

Comment: Ok. I am trying to give you better solution. :)

Comment: I try several solution but finally got this solution. I just edit my answer which is more optimized. @tux-world